# Martingales and dyadic intervals

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I am looking at the following and having a hard time showing that $X_n$ is a martingale.  How to do it?

---

[image]

Comment: Search for "martingale dyadic interval" and you will find some related stuff... since you are not providing any personal input on the question, this is probably the best which you will get..

Comment: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~conlon/math625/chapter2.pdf p. 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal F_n$ be the sigma field generated by the partition $I_{n,k}:1\leq k \leq 2^{n}$. Note that this sigma field is simply formed by all possible unions of these intervals. Also $\mathcal F_n , n=1,2,...$ is an increasing sequence of sigma fields. It is fairly easy to show that $\{EX|\mathcal F_n\}$ is a martingale for any integrable random variable $X$ and any increasing sequence of sigma fields $\{\mathcal F_n\}$. Now verify using definition of conditional expectation that $X_n=E(f|\mathcal F_n)$